# How to get back a pointer provider from `wire.FieldsOf`?

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am trying to use [google wire](https://github.com/google/wire) to wire a config field and failing hard at it.

I have the following wire entrypoint

```
type Config struct {
    UserConfig UserConfig
}

func initialize(ctx context.Context, cfg *Config) (*st, func(), error) {
    panic( // panic to be replaced by generated code
        wire.Build(
            InitializeUser,
            wire.FieldsOf(new(Config), "UserConfig"),
        ),
    )
}

func InitializeUser(config *UserConfig) *User {
    // initialize user from user config
}
```

I am trying to make the `UserConfig` field in the `Config`struct a provider without having to write a simple wrapper initializer just for that.

It is my understanding that `wire.FieldsOf` is supposed to do exactly this however it does not seem to work (keep geting `no provider found for *Config`). My guess is it only provides a `UserConfig` and not a `*UserConfig`.

Without changing the `UserConfig` field to a pointer or writing a initializer wrapper that takes a config and returns a `*UserConfig`, is there any way to do this in wire?

Comment: The body of `initialize` doesn't look like valid Go, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You were correct but it was just a typo on the post, it is correct on my side. I edited to fix the typo

Comment: I've never used `wire` so I don't really know how the code's supposed to look, but aren't you missing a [provider](https://github.com/google/wire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#defining-providers) for `*Config`? It seems like that's what the error is complaining about.

Comment: In [this example](https://github.com/google/wire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#use-fields-of-a-struct-as-providers) the `S` field is not a pointer.

Comment: I shortened the example but I have several other providers which themselves take in a `*Config` and I don't have to do anything so I think wire makes the Config a provider as well though I don't understand those details.
No, in the example `S` is not a pointer but I sort of expected, just as the struct provider documentation, it to make a provider of both pointer and non-pointer type. Might just be that it does not